# python: tar-ing downloaded files and base64 encoding tarball

Tags: javascript, python, tar

I'm trying to download some text files from a remote ftp server, which after downloading I would place them in a tarball, then base64 encoding the file and send it to the client via an opened web socket.

```
def download():
   if index_want == 1:

        tar_file = StringIO.StringIO()
        tar = open(mode="w:gz", fileobj=tar_file)

        for i ,l in enumerate(to_download):
            last_index = l.rfind('|')
            download_path = l[last_index+1:].strip()
            mda_url = '%s/%s'%(root_url, download_path)

            logger.debug('Downloading file %s/%s at %s', i, len(to_download), mda_url)

            mda_req = urllib2.Request(mda_url)
            mda_response = urllib2.urlopen(mda_req)
            f = StringIO.StringIO(mda_response.read())

            replace_path = mda_url.replace('/', '_')
            ti = TarInfo("%s.txt" %replace_path)
            ti.size = f.len

            tar.addfile(ti, f)

        tar.close()
        logger.info("Completed downloading all the requested files..")

    return tar_file


download().getvalue().encode('base64', 'strict')
```

Client Side code

```
  var content = messageObj['data'];
    var decodedContent = atob(content);

    var blob = new Blob([decodedContent], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
    saveAs(blob, "mda.tar");
```

On OSX, after I received the file and extracting it, the resultant file is `mda.tar.cpgz` and not the individual files I downloaded. Is there something wrong in my code?

**UPDATE**:

I stepping through the javascript code and in particular in this section

```
var blob = new Blob([decodedContent], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
            window.open((window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob));
```

The length of `decodedContent` is 11274, which seems to be correct. After running the above 2 lines, the saved files 17Kb large. There seems to be difference here.

Comment: try check if the sha1 hash of your received `mda.tar` matches that of the file you originally sent. if it does the problem may just be OS X bad at tar handling: http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/13/open-zip-cpgz-file/  ...if the sha1 doesn't match then problem is likely in your javascript b64 decoding

Comment: hmm it doesn't seem to match. In fact, the file size of the destination and source location isn't the same. I double checked, the encoded values sent and received are the same.